# Need help using an ArrayList

Tags: java

It seems that 20 regiments were in a continuous process of formation. The first had 1000 men, the second had 950, the third 900, and so on down to the twentieth regiment, which garrisoned only 50. During each week, 100 men were added to each regiment, and at week's end, the largest regiment was sent off to the front.This lasted for a total of 20 weeks.

For this program I have already managed to print out the original number of men for each regiment. But I am having difficult adding 100 men to each regiment.The adding men must be a method in the army class. I am getting the regiment objects using a .txt file. All this files contains is the names of regiments numbered 1-20.

I currently have no errors  my only problem is that I do not know how to add men to my regiment. I have to use the addMen method in the army class which I currently have blank.

```
    public class Regiment {

    private String name;       //name of regiment 
    private int regNumber;     //regiment number
    private int men;           // regiment men 

    public Regiment(int regNumber, String name, int men) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
        this.men = men;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getregNumber() {
        return regNumber;
    }

    public int getMen() {
        return men;
    }

    public int addMen2(int RegNumber) {
        int men = 1050 - (regNumber * 50);
        return men;
    }

    }
```

ArmyDataList:

```
    class ArmyDataList {

        public ArrayList<Regiment> list;

    public ArmyDataList() {
        list = new ArrayList<Regiment>();
    }

    public void AddToList(Regiment current) {
        list.add(current);
    }

    public void RemoveFromList(Regiment current) {
        list.remove(current);
    }

    public Regiment getLargest() {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        Regiment Reg1 = list.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Regiment current = list.get(i);      // get next regiment
            // is current regiment > largest
            if (current.getMen() > Reg1.getMen()) {
                Reg1 = current;
            }
        }
        return Reg1;

    }

    public void addMen() {

    }

    public String toString() {

        String out
                = String.format("%28s%12s%n", "Regiments", " Men")
                + String.format("%12s%n", "Number")
                + String.format("%12s%16s%14s%n", "=======", "===============",
                        "=========");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Regiment regim = list.get(i);
            int regNumber = regim.getregNumber();
            String name = regim.getName();
            int men = regim.addMen2(regNumber);

            out = out + String.format("%12s", regNumber)
                    + String.format("%16s", name)
                    + String.format("%10s", men)
                    + "\n";
        }
        return out + "\n";

    }
}
```

RegimentTest:

```
 public class RegimentTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {


  ArmyDataList army = new ArmyDataList();

      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("regiments.txt"));

      System.out.println("Report Summary:\n");

      while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
         String line = fileScan.nextLine();

         System.out.println(line);

         Scanner in = new Scanner(line) ;

        int regNumber = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        int men = 0 ; //men is set to 0 only because I havent add the men yet

        Regiment adder = new Regiment(regNumber, name, men );

         army.AddToList(adder) ;
      }

         System.out.println(army.toString());

      }
```

Comment: Is `addMen2` some sort of an init method? If so, why is it not in `ArmyDataList`?

Comment: You seem to be overthinking this. You have a class Regiment that contains number of men. Adding more should simply change that number. And `addMan2` based on what it does sounds more like `getStartingAmountOfMenBasedOnRegimentNumber`. It's java, go crazy with the names.

Comment: I did not know it was supposed to be in the army class. Will that help me with adding men to each regiment?

Comment: @Deitharis Can you show me an example of what I can do? I tried just making a method and adding 100 to men but it had no affect on my output.

Comment: Your `addMen` method is fine where it is. Though I agree with changing the name of `addMen2`. See my answer below

Comment: Ehh... We do not exactly know what you are doing. Your main method reads... something from file, possibly regiments, all with no men at all. And than it prints it. No wonder nothing happens.

Comment: Unrelated, but please pay close attention to how things are named, e.g., `list` isn't helpful. We know it's a list, it's in the declaration. What's it a list *of*?

Comment: Its a list of the regiment objects.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut i disagree with you, method `addMen2` is not fine, it is only do some calculations on provided data, it has nothing todo with `Regiment`

Comment: @user90283 Can you help me with this method? And also my addMen method the on that is supposed to add men to each regiment.

Comment: @user902383 It seems to initialize the number of men in that regiment, in accordance to his second sentence: "The first had 1000 men, the second had 950, the third 900, and so on down to the twentieth regiment, which garrisoned only 50"

Comment: On a side note: Your `addMen2()` is broken. It adds nothing, it only computes. Looking at how you use it you probably want to remove the declaration of `men` from it (change `int men = 1050 - (regNumber * 50);` to `men = 1050 - (regNumber * 50);`).

Comment: @RockOnRockOut i see what method is doing, but still it doesn't belong to regiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `setMen(int numberOfMen)` method to your `Regiment` class. Then in your `addMen()` method, you can do something like this:

```
public void addMen(){
    for(Regiment r : list){ //iterate through the list of regiments
        r.setMen(r.getMen() + 100); //add 100 men to each regiment
    }
}
```

The `setMen` method would look like this:

```
public void setMen(int numberOfMen){
    men = numberOfMen;
}
```

There is another issue with your `toString` method, where the regiment's `addMen2` method is called - right now you're just printing the number, not initializing the number of men. In the constructor for your `Regiment` class, replace the line

```
this.men = men;
```

with

```
this.men = addMen2(regNumber);
```

Then in your `toString` method, replace

```
int men = regim.addMen2(regNumber);
```

with

```
int men = regim.getMen();
```

Here is what your `main` should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    ArmyDataList army = new ArmyDataList();
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("regiments.txt"));
    System.out.println("Report Summary:\n");
    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(line);
        int regNumber = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        int men = 0 ; //men is set to 0 only because I havent add the men yet
        Regiment adder = new Regiment(regNumber, name, men );
        army.AddToList(adder);
    }
    System.out.println(army.toString()); //print out the initial # of men
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        army.addMen();
    System.out.println(army.toString()); //print the final # of men
}
```

Comment: This method belongs in the army class right? If so, when I call it in my tester it does not change the amount of men.

Comment: It should change the number of men. Right now I don't see you calling the function in your tester class.

Comment: @Name you have overriden toString method. Badly.

Comment: @Deltharis I know but I am going to fix that later. Just need to my addMen method working first.

Comment: @Name circular dependency. What you see, your output, is what toString writes. If it's wrong (and it IS) you can't use it's output to judge how addMen works.

Comment: @Deitharis Alright, can you help me with that? i have to print that 20 different times in which each one the number of men increases by 100.

Comment: @Name first things first: in your `Regiment` constructor, instead of doing `this.men = men`, you should call `addMen2(regNumber)` - this will initialize your regiment to its corresponding number of men, not 0.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut That helps, but it is still not changing the number of men. What I'm doing is writing a while loop that runs until 20 weeks has passed. And in that loop i print the to string method and then call the add men method. It just gives me the same amount of men each time.

Comment: Did you make the changes I wrote in the updated answer?

Comment: Yes, I made all the changes you made. The number of men remains the same.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut Was I supposed to call the addMethod in my tester class.

Comment: You mean, call `addMen()`? Yes, you should do that at the end of your `main`, the call another `toString` to see how it changed.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. I tried calling another toString but I got no changes to my number of men. Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Alright that helps me thanks alot. But do you know why I am getting very large negative numbers for my output.

Comment: What numbers are you using for your regiment number?

Comment: I actually got to work. Never mind. Lastly, if I wanted to add a different number of men to a regiment ( based on there name). Can I just use an if/else statement?

Comment: Yes. Within the `addMen` method, you can add any conditions you want to the number of men added.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry to bother you one more time, but I just noticed that it only added 100 once. All the other times it has the same numbers.

Comment: Can you show me how you would make the setMen method just to make sure I did it correctly.

Comment: @Name I don't know if you're still looking for this, but the web browser crashed and couldn't reply to you. It crashed after I made the edit so the `setMen` method has been there for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

in `Regiment` get rid of method `addMen2`, and replace it with

```
public void addMen(int men) {
this.men +=men;
}
```

then in your army you could have method

```
 public void addMen(int men) {
      for(Regiment regiment : list){
         regiment.addMen(men);
      }
   }
```

that will be simplest solution to add 100 men to each regiment,

other thing is, your `toString` is bit nasty, regiment should know how meny soldiers it ghas, you shouldnt need additional method to calculate it (reason why i recommend you to trash `addMen2` method)

to initiate your  `Regiment`, use constructor. You want to have regiments in sizes 1000, 1950, 1900 etc, do it when you are creating them

```
while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
         String line = fileScan.nextLine();
         System.out.println(line);
         Scanner in = new Scanner(line) ;
        int regNumber = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        int men = 1050 - (regNumber * 50);

        Regiment adder = new Regiment(regNumber, name, men );

         army.AddToList(adder) ;
      }
```

Comment: It still does not change the number of men.

Comment: Am i supposed to call my addMen method in my tester class.

Comment: @Name yes, you need to call `addMen` in your tester class, this should increment all your regiments by given number of soldiers

Comment: @Name third snippet allow you to create regiment with right amount of soldiers in first place. Other thing is, you could consider change container for your regiments to queue